# C# Class select multiple fields in Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, xamarin, toarray

I want to select multiple fields from a list. This is my code:

```
string[] NamesArray = Users
            .Select(i => new {  i.FirstName, i.LastName })
            .Distinct()
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.FirstName)
            .ToArray();
```

When I use this code the error is: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'anonymous type: string FirstName, string LastName []' to string[]'
What can I do???

Comment: See the answer now, hope will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of anonymous select so when you select like `(i => new {  i.FirstName, i.LastName })` it will give you a list of object that each of object have `FirstName` and `LastName` which is not string and can't be cats to `string`.

so you should do something like this:

```
string[] NamesArray = Users.OrderByDescending(i => i.FirstName)
         .Select(i => i.FirstName + " " + i.LastName)
         .Distinct()
         .ToArray();
```

if you want to select anonymous value then you can't cast it to `string[]` the best way is `var` like:

```
var NamesArray = Users.OrderByDescending(i => i.FirstName)
             .Select(i => new { i.FirstName , i.LastName})
             .Distinct()
             .ToArray();
```

but it is also give you a list of object with `FirstName` and `LastName` properties.

but another workaround would be like:

```
var NamesArray = Users.OrderByDescending(i => i.FirstName)
            .Select(i => new string[] { i.FirstName, i.LastName })
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();
foreach(string[] str in NamesArray)
{
     string firstName = str[0];
     string lastName = str[1];
}
```

Or:

```
List<string[]> NamesArray = Users.OrderByDescending(i => i.FirstName)
        .Select(i => new string[] { i.FirstName, i.LastName })
        .Distinct().ToList();
```

Or:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> NamesArray = Users.OrderByDescending(i => i.FirstName)
            .Select(i => new string[] { i.FirstName, i.LastName })
            .Distinct();
foreach(string[] str in NamesArray)
{
    string firstName = str[0];
    string lastName = str[1];
}
```

anyway you can't cast it directly to `string[]` means `NamesArray` can't be `string[]`.

Comment: Now it says: "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or memeber acces"?

Comment: and what do you mean with sss?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk, Yes it was wrong at the first go, I have edited, try it again.

Comment: I was looking to the code, but there is one problem with it. Your code is creating a string with 2 values, but I want 2 separate values (not in 1 string).

Comment: So you can't cast it to `string[]` array, I explained why.